# Seleccionar secciones de una lista

Tags: python

Si tengo una lista en Python:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer una selección de varias secciones de la lista y que salgan fusionadas en otra lista?

Por ejemplo, seleccionar desde la posición 0 a la 2 (`['a', 'b', 'c']`)
y desde la posición 5 al final (`['f', 'g', 'h']`) y obtener como resultado la lista `['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h']`

Edito para concretar un poco más, siguiendo la recomendación FJSevilla, al que le agradezco su aportación. Lo que busco es esto:

```
>>> # Tengo una lista con datos de una variable en tres dimensiones, por ejemplo
>>> data=[
...     [
...     [22,25,31,24,32,12,13],
...     [13,26,14,11,12,24,22],
...     [10,23,14,22,33,14,24]
...     ],
...     [
...     [13,24,31,24,14,24,34],
...     [11,22,33,13,23,42,12],
...     [14,52,12,33,22,44,12]
...     ]
... ]
>>> # De ella quiero sacar una lista con los datos de las dos primeras variables
>>> # y segmentos escogidos por mi de la ultima en cualquier orden, por ejemplo [5:]+[:3]
>>> # buscando obtener un output como esto:
output=[
[
[12 13 22 25 31]
[24 22 13 26 14]
[14 24 10 23 14]
]
[
[24 34 13 24 31]
[42 12 11 22 33]
[44 12 14 52 12]
]
]
>>> #He probado asi pero me da error de sintaxis:
>>> out=data[:][:][[5:]+[3:]]
 File "<stdin>", line 1
out=data[:][:][[5:]+[3:]]
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> #Así obtengo el resultado deseado:
>>> out=data[0][0][5:]+data[0][0][:3]
>>> print out
[12, 13, 22, 25, 31]

>>> #Yo quiero que me imprima eso, para todo x e y:
>>> #Pero cuando hago lo siguiente me imprime toda la matriz de datos:
>>> out= data[:][:][5:]+data[:][:][:3]
>>> print out
[[[22, 25, 31, 24, 32, 12, 13], [13, 26, 14, 11, 12, 24, 22], [10, 23, 14, 22, 33, 14, 24]], [[13, 24, 31, 24, 14, 24, 34], [11, 22, 33, 13, 23, 42, 12], [14, 52, 12, 33, 22, 44, 12]]]
```

Comment: Atreyuk, bienvenid@ a SOes. Pienso que tu pregunta es valida, pero es demasiado ampliar, ya que pueden existir muchas formas de hacer lo que planteas. Por favor, incluye el código que actualmente estas usando para resolver tu problema e indica en donde tienes dificultades. Tambien indica tambien la versión de Python que estas utilizando. Para incluir tu codigo de la mejor manera, revisa el articulo: [mcve]. Haciendo todo esto, evitaras que tu pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Usas slicing o rebanado de listas y luego concatenas:

```
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
>>> sl = l[:3] + l[5:]
>>> sl
['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

La sintaxis general es:

```
lista[start:end:step]
```

Unas cuantas observaciones:

- El elemento con índice definido en `start` se incluye en el corte, el elemento correspondiente a `end` no se incluye:

  ```
  >>> l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
  >>> l[1:3]
  ['b', 'c']
  ```
- Si no se define `start` o `end` se entiende que es desde el principio de la lista o hasta el final de la lista respectivamente (incluyendo en este caso el último elemento):

  ```
  >>> l[:5]
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

  >>> l[4:]
  ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

  >>> l[:]
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
  ```
- Con `step` definimos el salto que damos entre elementos:

  ```
  >>> l[::2]
  ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
  ```

  Como vemos retorna la lista completa pero cogiendo solo cada dos elementos.
- Se permiten índices negativos como es lógico (igual que al acceder por índice a una lista):

  ```
  >>> l[3:-2]
  ['d', 'e', 'f']
  ```
- El paso (step) también puede ser negativo, lo cual permite por ejemplo invertir la lista:

  ```
  >>> l[::-1]
  ['h', 'g', 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']

  >>> l[::-2]
  ['h', 'f', 'd', 'b']
  ```
- Lo que se retorna es un nuevo objeto, una nueva lista. Con `l[:]` obtenemos una copia de la lista original completa (***shallow copy***):

  ```
  >>> lista = [1, 1, [3]]
  >>> copia = lista[:]
  >>> copia == lista
  True
  >>> id(copia) == id(lista)
  False
  >>> copia
  [1, 1, [3]]
  >>> lista
  [1, 1, [3]]
  >>> copia[2].append(4)
  >>> copia[0] = 14  
  >>> lista
  [1, 1, [3, 4]]
  >>> copia
  [14, 1, [3, 4]]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Al final he encontrado la manera de hacerlo. Dejo aquí esta solución que encontré leyendo sobre operaciones con matrices en Python por si a alguien le es de utilidad. Si a alguien se le ocurre una mejor, más simple, por favor que la ponga.

```
>>> matriz = [[data[i][j][5:]+data[i][j][:3] for j in range(3)] for i in range(2)]
>>> print matriz
[[[12, 13, 22, 25, 31], [24, 22, 13, 26, 14], [14, 24, 10, 23, 14]], [[24, 34, 13, 24, 31], [42, 12, 11, 22, 33], [44, 12, 14, 52, 12]]]
```